# Laravel - Action not defined but it is defined

Tags: laravel, controller, laravel-blade

I get this error when i try loading blade.php

```
Action App\Http\Controllers\InventoryItemController@change not defined.
```

I have change function in InventoryItemController

```
    public function change($new_status)
{
        //  
}
```

This started when I wanted to make button

```
<a href="{{action('InventoryItemController@change', $inventoryitem['new_status'])}}"class="btn btn-info">Confirm Change</a>
```

I did everything same when i made Edit button and that button works normally.

**UPDATE 1**

My button looks like this now

```
<a href="{{route('change', [$inventoryitem['new_status'], 
$inventoryitem['asset_id']])}}"class="btn btn-info">Confirm Change</a>
```

and my change function is this

```
public function change($new_status, $asset_id) 
    {
        $asset = Asset::find($asset_id);
        $asset->status = $new_status;
        return redirect('showasset', compact('asset','asset_id'));  
    }
```

and my route in web is like this

```
Route::get('change/{$new_status}/{$asset_id}','InventoryItemController@change')->name('change');
```

But after i click button it just redirect me to url .../change/4/1 and that's it. Nothing changes.

Comment: What is your route ? Use `route` instead of `action`
My bad, don't undertsand correctly your code. Using route instead of action is better in general. Can I see the controller (all not just the method )? And where did you store your controller file ?

Comment: Your passed parameter should look like ['new_status' => $inventoryitem['new_status']] or something like that depending on your code

Comment: @DessaugesAntoine If i put route instead of action its same thing Route not defined. Controller file is where every controller file is, in app/http/Controllers/

Comment: @NoOorZ24 I need to pass new_status so in my change function i can change status of certain item thats in another table.

Comment: @Zolak94 Just to be sure. In this cas we know to see what is `$inventoryitem` and more of your controller file.

Comment: can you post how is your route defined?

Comment: @Zolak94 check if you are not passing null value, does your url have parameter in it? how does it look?

Comment: @NoOorZ24 this is my url, mysite.com/inventoryitems/1

Comment: @Pol I dont have defined route for change function because that button just need to change something, it's not redirecting anywhere.

Comment: @Zolak94 We can't use your url (404). And your change function is in your controller (you didn't put it in your edit ? )

Answer (score 3):

Using `Action` is deprecated in Laravel

You can use routes instead.

Define Routes  in your routes files (/routes/web.php) like.

```
Route::get('change/{status}','InventoryItemController@change')->name('change');
```

and then in your view

```
<a href="{{route('change', $inventoryitem['new_status'])}}"class="btn btn-info">Confirm Change</a>
```

In your controller use.

```
public function change ($status){
  // rest of the function.
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I need to pass parameter to change function. with this it only redirects me to /change page. which i don't have. What i need is button that when clicked, changes status of item in another table.

Comment: see the updated answer `Route::get('change/{status}','InventoryItemController@change')->name('change');
`

Comment: now i get this error
`Missing required parameters for [Route: change] [URI: change/{status}].`

Comment: @Zolak94 in your change change function you can get the new status by passing it as a param. see my updated answer

Comment: There is no name of function in you example, but still its same error.

Comment: But still its same error. `Missing required parameters for [Route: change] [URI: change/{$status}].`

Comment: I was passing value thats null. When i changed it, its working perfect. Thank you a lot for your effort!

Answer (score 1):

Define your controller's method in route file as following:

Route::get('url/{new_status}',InventoryItemController@change);

**Answer on UPDATE 1**

```
    public function change($new_status, $asset_id) 
    {
        $asset = Asset::find($asset_id);
        $asset->status = $new_status;
        $asset->save();     
        return view('your_view_path',compact('variable1','variable2'));
    }
```

Comment: I changed return redirect to return view, but it still goes to this url `.../change/4/1` (I put ... because of my safety for mine website)

Comment: As a tip : if you want to return it back to the page where your "Confirm Change" button exist..you can do return redirect()->back() instead of return view.

Comment: please make sure you have **showasset.blade.php** in your project

Comment: I do have it, but the problem is that when i call method from controller, it does nothing like there is nothing in that method.

Answer (score 0):

Final error was in my route

```
Route::get('change/{$new_status}/{$asset_id}','InventoryItemController@change')->name('change');
```

It should be like this

```
Route::get('change/{new_status}/{asset_id}','InventoryItemController@change')->name('change');
```

After that change everything is working flawlessly. Thank you for your help guys!